# html5/Javascript - How to upload Multiple folders?

Tags: javascript, html

**HTML CODE**

```
<input type="file" id="FileUpload" onchange="selectFolder(event)" webkitdirectory mozdirectory msdirectory odirectory directory multiple />
```

**or**

```
<input type="file" id="file1" name="abc" onchange="Filter(); upload.disabled = false;" webkitdirectory mozdirectory msdirectory odirectory directory AllowMultiple="true"/>
```

multiple and webkitdirectory are not working as expected

Comment: What browser are you using?

Comment: Latest chrome browser on Windows PC

Comment: It can't be done at the moment. A single directory yes, but not multiple. I've been waiting years for this feature.